# difference between IDs and class in CSS

Tags: html, css

by definition ID same Id cannot be used multiple time in the same webpage or to multiple different elements on the same webpage and also we can only use one ID to any element, multiple IDs cannot be used at the same time on one element.

In my example below I used same IDs for different elements and also used same IDs to define different rules. But still it works as expected. Could some one please explain me what exactly is happening here.

```
 <html>
 <head>
  <style type = "text/css">
        .redtext{color:red;}
        .greentext{color:green;}
        .fontweight{font-weight:bold;}
        #Barcelona{color:blue;}
        #Chelsea{color:yellow;}
        #Chelsea {color:blue;}

    </style>
  </head>
    <body>

      <p class= "redtext"> I want this paragraph to be RED </p>
      <p class = "greentext"> I want this paragraph to be GREEN</p>
      <div id = "Chelsea"> Liverpool want this one on  bottom right  </div>
      <div id = "Chelsea"> Liverpool want this one on bottom left </div>

      <p id = "Chelsea"> I want this paragraph to be GREEN</p>
      <h1 id = "Barcelona"> multiple usage of same id </h1>
      <p class= "fontweight redtext"> am I in bold ?</p>
      </body>

     </html>
```

output after running this script.

---

I want this paragraph to be RED

I want this paragraph to be GREEN

Liverpool want this one on bottom right
Liverpool want this one on bottom left
I want this paragraph to be GREEN

multiple usage of same id

am I in bold ?

---

after running this example I can say that IDs can be used for multiple elements and same IDs can have different styles defined.

Please help me understand this.

Comment: Just because you _can_ use the same `id` multiple times does not make it valid HTML.  Using the the same `id` multiple times in a document will cause it to fail any validation. And CSS and JavaScript operating on that document may have undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out the difference by going [here](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/)

For an immediate answer, you cannot have two id's with the same name but different attributes in one document. You also may not have two different ones in a single sets of quotations.

Though, the fact that you cannot have the same class name with different attributes in one document still applies, you may, in one pair of quotations have different class'

>

For the multiple id's in one class,

> class="classname classname"

This would work while

> id="idname idname"

This would not work

>

If I did not answer your specific question please let me know.

Comment: yeah having same ids with different attributes still works which is like method overloading. But when tried an element with multiple Ids did not work. so the only real implementation advantage of class over Ids is that multiple class can be used for an element at the same time .

Answer (score 0):

The id must be unique, I mind, you can not have two elements with the same value for attribute "id", while classes can be used in several elements smoothly. Furthermore, the "id" are more powerfull than classes,  the CSS rules that target the elements through its "id" will have greater strength than those using their classes.